# If A and B are in the same ship

Tags: grammatical-number

If A and B are in the same ship and it has been mentioned, and they are boys, can I just say 'he is in a ship'? Or should I say 'they are in a ship'? For example if two people are in a ship, 'one person is in a ship' is wrong expression, but 'two people are in a ship is correct expression. So, only 'they are in a ship' is correct?

Comment: More context, please? I can't figure out exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @MarielS I add some example.

Comment: It is still impossible to know what your question is. Please try and ask a question we can understand and answer.

Comment: Who are ON a ship? John and Mary are "on" a ship. If you have already mentioned the people's names, then there's no need to repeat "He is "in" a ship". The problem arises if both people are the same sex. Saying "he" would be unclear.

Comment: Why is **One person is ON a ship** wrong? Who said that?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You know 'a dog has one leg' is normally wrong. A dog has four legs.

Comment: “I have a child, his name is Tom, **he is at school** now.” Usually there is more than one child in a school.

Comment: I mean if more than one child are at school and they are mentioned, can I still use 'he' in 'he is at school'?

Comment: Sorry, but that's all, there's no more context.

Comment: Is this an exercise question? Is it from a test? Is this a short story? Have the names of the people been previosly mentioned?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I made it.

Comment: If you are speaking of both A and B, of course it's _they_ - why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not be able to say "He is in a ship." because there are two people and "he" is not plural. "He" means "a male". You would have to say "They are in a ship". It should also actually "They are on a ship" and not "They are in a ship". Also, "One person is on a ship" would be correct because there is one person on the ship. "Only one person is on a ship" would be wrong.

Comment: Grammatically speaking "One person's on a ship" is correct, but no one would say that if there were hundreds of passengers and a ship crew. The statement sounds as if there is no one else on board.

Comment: I wonder why in test in the section of describing a picture 'one person eats something' is considered to be wrong even though two people eat something.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @anysome `I wonder why in test in the section of describing a picture 'one person eats something' is considered to be wrong even though two people eat something` and now we have the context, finally. If we say one person is eating but we can see two people eating, it's called misinformation. Grammatically, the sentence is correct but it is not ***accurately*** describing reality.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I think It is true to speakers, but when it comes to  listeners, they perceive in a different way, so it becomes misinformation.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Oh, misinformation can mean 'inaccurate information.'

Answer (score 2):

This is not about grammar. This is just about meaning.

"He" and "they" mean different things.

If Peter and Paul are on a ship...

> Two people are on the ship

Is grammatically correct.  We don't know if it is true or not. There might be more people on the ship.

> One person is on the ship

Is grammatically correct.  But it is not true.

> Peter is on the ship

Is grammatically correct and true.

> Where is Peter?
>
> He is on the ship.

Is grammatically correct and true.

> Where are Peter and Paul
>
> They are on the ship.

Is correct and true.